# Kivy Returns Blank Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

so i was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yMHHC36tT0) video, and i was following as he was, i wrote the code just like he did, but when i run, it gives no errors, but returns a blank screen instead of a calculator UI, the same thing happened with another video.. (P.S my kivy version is 1.10.1)

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Erfan\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-01- 
01_23.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 
23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif 
(img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 NVIDIA 353.62'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not 
docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

This is my code, there were no errors.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
kivy.require("1.10.1")

class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):
pass

class CalculatorApp(App):

def LoginForm(self):
return CalcGridLayout

calcApp = CalculatorApp()
calcApp.run()
```

It redirects to a file i created called "Calculator.kv"
these are the code in the file.

```
<CustButton@Button>:
font_size: 32

<CalcGridLayout>:
id: calculator
display: entry
rows: 5
padding: 10
spacing: 10

BoxLayout:
    TextInput:
        id: entry
        font_size: 32
        multiline: False


BoxLayout:
    spacing: 10

    CustButton:
        text: "7"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "8"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "9"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "+"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
BoxLayout:
    spacing: 10

    CustButton:
        text: "4"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "5"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "6"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "-"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
BoxLayout:
    spacing: 10

    CustButton:
        text: "1"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "2"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "3"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "*"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
BoxLayout:
    spacing: 10

        CustButton:
        text: "AC"
        on_press: entry.text = ""
    CustButton:
        text: "0"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "="
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
    CustButton:
        text: "/"
        on_press: entry.text += self.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! i found the problem, the problem was that i may have used LoginForm, which is completely different than what we need so what i basically needed to do was to change LoginForm to build.

I mean from

```
def LoginForm(self):
```

to

```
def build(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the brackets after return CalcGridLayout in the python file

Comment: It doesnt make any difference.