# Kivy Window Returning Blank

Tags: python, kivy

So I've been trying to make a learning app but it seems that the window just never returns the proper build. I've checked posts like: [Some troubles using Screen Manager without .kv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487117/some-troubles-using-screen-manager-without-kv-file?newreg=45d67883bf2745b4bf9e136a6dd9d09e) and [Kivy Returns Blank Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994421/kivy-returns-blank-screen) but it seems like neither of them helps my case?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
Config.set("input","mouse","mouse,multitouch_on_demand")

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MainMenu(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.GradeOne = Button(text="First Grade", size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .7})

class FirstGrade(Screen):
    def buid(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstGrade, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.GradeOne = Button(text="Math", size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .7})

class MainBuild(App):
    def build(self):
       SM = ScreenManagement()
       SM.add_widget(MainMenu(name='Main Menu'), size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .7})
       SM.add_widget(FirstGrade(name='FirstGrade'))
       return SM

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainBuild().run()
```

If you guys could help that would do wonders, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I forgot to add the widgets to the screen. I also needed to rename a button

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).